# Transfer my fullCalendar events to user's google calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

Need to Transfer my fullCalendar Events to user's google calendar using js.

I have done RND about how I can achieve this but unable to get an answer.

```
import React from 'react';
import { FullCalendar } from './lib/FullCalendar';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';


export default function() {

    return (
        <div className="content" >
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                      <div className="col-md-12 nopaddb">
                        <div className="card card-calendar">
                            <div className="card-content ps-child">
                                <FullCalendar options={this.options} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I just want to transfer my fullCalendar events which are currently showing on my fullCalendar perfectly into the user's own google calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions here:

- Use [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/) to connect to the user calendar and insert / update the events in a specific calendar so they match your app's
- Use a [caldav server](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) to host the user calendar on a public URL and add it manually to google calendar

I would go for the first solution which allow your events to stay private